# Regex replace characters and keep text inside adding span tag

Tags: c#, regex

I have the following regex:

```
var formatted = Regex.Replace(query, "#[A-Za-z0-9]+#", "<span class=\"text-danger\">[$1]</span>");
```

What I am trying to do is replace # but keep the text between and adding a span at the same time.

So for example #name# would become `<span class="text-danger">(name)</span>`

and  #title# would become `<span class="text-danger">(title)</span>`etc

But I'm unable to get the above to work

----------------UPDATE------------------------------

I have tried all options, the question that I am marked a duplicate for I have read before and the answer did not work

I have also tried `var formatted = Regex.Replace(query, "#([A-Za-z0-9]+)#", "[<span class=\"text-danger\">$1</span>]");`

and

var formatted = Regex.Replace(query, "#([A-Za-z0-9]+)#", "[$1]");

But none work

Comment: You are missing parentheses around the part of the pattern you need to keep. `"#([A-Za-z0-9]+)#"`

Comment: Also i think you do not need "[" and "]" around replacement group $1

Comment: Hi Wiktor Stribiżew  and  Pablo notPicasso I have tried what you said earlier and none work

Comment: This works:

string text = "#name#";
string editedText = 
Regex.Replace(text, "\\#(\\w+)\\#", "<span class=\"text-danger\">($1)</span>");
  
Console.WriteLine(editedText);

Fiddle:
https://dotnetfiddle.net/6bhZzN

Comment: Hi Jasper Thanks

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.